# handle image URL (.htaccess) by passed variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to handle my image URLs in two different ways.
First, when the browser calls for: 
http://example.com/image.jpg (need to be shown)

Second, when the browser calls for:
http://example.org/image.jpg?actionId=123 (need to be URL rewrote to index.php?actionId=123)

The point is, when the URL has it's specified variable, then we need to redirected to the index.php with that variable and it's value.

I'm using .htaccess with mod_rewrite, which is the following now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

So it's checks for existing file or directory, any other way, it's passed to index.php in 'q' param.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example you don't need to do anything, the image will be shown if it exists. Therefore you only need to consider the case with the query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} actionId=([^&]+)
RewriteRule \.jpg$ index.php?actionId=%1 [L]
```

If there are other parameters that you also need to pass to to `index.php` then just doing the rewrite should be enough as the query string is sent by default. To be sure use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} actionId=([^&]+)
RewriteRule \.jpg$ index.php [QSA,L]
```